# Echo all a href (or div) from html by class name

Tags: php

I want to be able to echo from a web page any element (and content) by its class name.

in the html page i have somting like this:

> ```
> <a class="one" href="#"><img class="imagine" src="/css/full.png"/><span class="txt">one</span></a>      
> <a class="two" href="#"><img class="imagine" src="/css/full.png"/><span class="txt">two</span></a>      
> <a class="thry" href="#"><img class="imagine" src="/css/full.png"/><span class="txt">thry</span></a>      
> <a class="one" href="#"><img class="imagine" src="/css/full.png"/><span class="txt">one</span></a>      
> <a class="thry" href="#"><img class="imagine" src="/css/full.png"/><span class="txt">thry</span></a>      
> <a class="two" href="#"><img class="imagine" src="/css/full.png"/><span class="txt">two</span></a>
> ```

I have follwing php code that is doing something but not everything:

```
<?php 
$url = "./div.html"; 
$html = @file_get_contents($url); 
$content= $html; 
$first_step  = explode('<a class="one">' , $content );  
$second_step = explode("</a>" , 
$first_step[1] );  
echo  $second_step[0]; 
?>
```

This code finds what i need but its echo only the first match and it echo only the content between `<a class="one"` and `</a>`

i need to echo all matches an to echo all the element a href content.

Answer (score 0):

if the web page You want to parse is valid XHTML, you can use SimpleXML in PHP to parse its markup. Here is the link:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

By using SimpleXML, You can iterate over the nodes looking for "a" elements and extract the "href" attribute.